# Reset checkbox checked state go back from history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

In the following example, I use checkbox for making a pure CSS dropdown navigation, also available in this **[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pjbf3eyb/)**.

Open that fiddle, click "Menu", click "Link 1", and click the "Back" button on the browser toolbar, as you can see the checkbox remains checked, so the navigation is still open.

My question is - would it be possible to reset that checkbox to unchecked automatically when going back from the browser history? Any suggestions please? Do I need to use Javascript/jQuery?

HTML

```
<label for="m">Menu</label>
<input id="m" type="checkbox">
<nav id="n">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="//example.com">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#n {
  display: none;
}
#m:checked ~ #n {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No need for JS or CSS, just add `autocomplete="off"` to the checkbox. This will prevent the browser from caching the 'checked' status.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6g5u8wkb/

Also, if you have multiple checkboxes, I beleive you can add `autocomplete="off"` to the `form` element to apply the effect to all inputs fields.

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` is ignored by IE11!! It will still restore the state!

Comment: This just hung me up for hours. I couldn't understand why even though my model value was updating the checked state the checkbox would always be checked until I refreshed the page.

Comment: How to achieve the above problem's solution in alpine Js

Comment: @AkshayKumar I'm not familiar with Alpine JS, but this answer doesn't involve Javascript at all, so it shouldn't matter. Just needs to be done in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#m").prop('checked',false );
});
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#m").prop('checked',false );
});
```

```css
#n {
  display: none;
}
#m:checked ~ #n {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="m">Menu</label>
<input id="m" type="checkbox">
<nav id="n">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="//example.com">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the other comments, if you are writing an AJAX driven page that uses pushState/replaceState, and the back button would not actually reload a page (i.e. no HTTP request), you can listen for the `popState` event and clear the checkbox.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   $("#m").prop('checked',false );
};
```

It's a HTML 5 feature that's not fully supported across all browsers (although support is pretty good)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Other options would be to use libraries like history.js, jquery-bbq, sammyjs, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

add `autocomplete="off"` to the checkbox.

Comment: This worked well on my pseudo checkbox's and pseudo radio button's.