# How not to keep the state of a checkbox through the history?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a checkbox to create a mobile menu. Simplified, it looks like that:

```css
input, ul {
  display: none;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" />
<label for="toggle-menu">Menu</label>
<ul>
  <li><a href="duckduckgo.com">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works well, except for a thing: when the user navigates in another page using the menu, and then go back is the history, the checkbox state is kept, and thus the menu is displayed.

Is it possible to prevent this, preferably without Javascript? To say it in another words, I'd like the menu to never be displayed when a page is accessed to, even through the navigation in the history. The user must click on the label to see the menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset checkbox checked state go back from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933043/reset-checkbox-checked-state-go-back-from-history)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try autocomplete off. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: It works, at least on Firefox and Chrome! Is it reliable, though? I've read its documentation, and unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems that it is invalid on a checkbox type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefautocomplete

Comment: I just checked https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_global_attributes_autocomplete i think it's fine but it depends on your users.

Comment: I meant the attribute `autocomplete` on an `input` of type `checkbox`. The MDN doc says: "*This attribute has no effect on input types that do not return numeric or text data, being valid for all input types except checkbox, radio, file*".

Comment: well the description says "except checkbox" so i think it should work fine

Comment: It says "This attribute is valid for all input types except checkbox". That means that it is invalid on a checkbox.

Comment: oh you're right i misunderstood.. i'm not sure then sorry

Comment: I've just verified, the W3C validator marks the autocomplete attribute on a checkbox as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding autocomplete="off" stops browser from remembering the checkbox state.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu" autocomplete="off" />
```